# Does python reorder instructions for optimization?

Tags: python, compiler-optimization

I know that C & C++ compilers reorder operations (as long as the [as-if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) rule holds) for optimization. Does something similar occur with compiled python code?

Comment: Python is an interpreted language.  Do you mean the compiled C binaries for some functions, or?

Comment: @anon01 how about .pyc files?

Comment: I don't think so. Just did `dis.dis` on two functions just incrementing two variables, either alternating between the two or first one, then the other. In both cases, it would `LOAD_FAST` and `STORE_FAST` for each individual assignment, even if it used the same variable again in the next one. So even if lines were ordered differently, it would do the same operations, just in a different order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, Python itself is neither interpreted nor compiled; *implementations* of a language can be either.

That said, the most common implementation (CPython) *does* compile your Python source code. The target is not your processor, though, but a virtual stack machine that then interprets the resulting byte code.

Reordering instructions is done to take advantage of your processor's ability to execute multiple instructions at once, interleaving things like instruction fetching, data access, etc. The stack machine implemented by CPython is not that complicated; individual byte codes can't be decomposed into smaller "microinstructions" that would benefit from the type of re-ordering you are thinking of.

Answer (score 1):

Python is an interpreted language. Even when you "compile" it to a `.pyc` file, that contains byte codes, not machine instructions.

Reordering byte code instructions is not likely to make any difference in performance. Each byte code corresponds to a number of instructions in the interpreter itself, so pipeline effects that instruction reordering takes advantage of are not available at this high level.